# Using TypeScript intersection type with a native Promise and a jQuery Promise as the await statement operand

Tags: jquery, typescript, promise, async-await

I'm going to use a TypeScript intersection type as:

```
Promise<void> & JQueryPromise<void>
```

as an operand of the await statement.

So, my code is:

```
const test4 = async () => {
    let p: Promise<void> & JQueryPromise<void>;
    await p;
}
```

I added `@types/jquery` to get IntelliSense for jQuery. But, TypeScript give the **error TS1320: Type of 'await' operand must either be a valid promise or must not contain a callable 'then' member.** error.

There is no error if I declare the `p` variable as

1. only a native promise:

   ```
   const test1 = async () => {
       let p: Promise<void>;
       await p;
   }
   ```
2. only a jQuery promise:

   ```
   const test2 = async () => {
       let p: JQueryPromise<void>;
       await p;
   }
   ```
3. using a TypeScript union type:

   ```
   const test3 = async () => {
       let p: Promise<void> | JQueryPromise<void>;
       await p;
   }
   ```

You can see this error in the [Stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zucoy6?file=main.ts).

I can successfully use a jQuery Promise in the await statement. See the [CodePen sample](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MOREzd?editors=0011). A TypeScript union type works fine as well. A union type allows using only shared members of both types. An intersection type allows using members from both types. So, why does not my intersection type work if it just provides more members than my union type?

In addition, why does my union type return `then` as a property (which is incorrect, I believe):
[image]

but, my intersection type returns `then` as a method (which is correct, I believe):
[image]

Are these related issues?

Comment: All of your examples work fine for me with `typescript@2.6.1` and `jQuery@3.2.1`.

Comment: It's necessary to add `@types/jquery`.

Comment: Occurred to me as well, I'm on TS 3.2.2. Not a TS developer but one thing you can do is cast your intersection type to any one promise type and then await on it.. like: `let p: Promise<void> | JQueryPromise<void>; let q: Promise<void> = p;
    await q;`